# 16th century Latin (England) Transcription/Translation of Recipe for Braggot

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-check, abbreviations, transcription

I study how mead was made (and what it tasted like!) before about 1750 CE. I am not a linguist, and acknowledge my rudimentary knowledge of Latin grammar/tenses/etc. (learning all the time).

I’m struggling with transcription of a recipe for braggot (ale with honey and spices) from a 16th c. English medical compendium. The image highlights the abbreviation which sparked this request, but a few others are giving me trouble as well, marked with ? in the working transcription.

[image: Wellcome MS 757 f.25r]

The passage is a recipe for braggot, an alcoholic drink made from ale and honey with added spices. My working transcription (where I am sure I have errors due to my developing understanding of the details of Latin grammar) reads:

> Rx vj lagens servica facienda, accipe una lagenem servicie et unam quart mellis simuler p??dur super igne lene et dispumetur tunc fer bullierint accipe unce j piperis et modice galange et haec pulvdizat in ponantur praedicto lignare, deinde a servisa frigida depone fo?es et p??dur haec servisa in mundo vase et tunc p??dur lagena servisa specificitur ad residuam servicia et bene obturetur et stes per ij as vas ?aunqui?it? bibatur.” (Wellcome MS 757, f.25r)

Note cervisia (ale/beer) is consistently spelled here servica,

I’ve looked through Capelli, Martin, and used various rules of thumb (e.g. Capelli introductory information and Library of Congress resource guide) – including skimming for similar abbreviations since the household/agriculture and medical Latin I usually see is not well represented in these references. In all cases I’ve looked for an expansion that provides a word that works in context. I've worked through a number of variations of “praedi---”  but none seem right to me. I’ve used logeion in an effort to hone in on a word that works. I’ve also tried reverse translation for individual words with the meaning I believe it should have in English to try to find a workable word that can be backing into the abbreviation. I’m stumped.

In addition to the word that appears three times, the last line is in question with the insertion mark for 'vas'and what might be a partial erasure of the next word.

Context:
--- Similar recipes call for taking a portion of ale wort, boiling it with honey and often the spices then returning to the remainder and fermenting, which is the pattern this appears to follow. I have compared it to about a dozen other recipes. Other instructions are possible. This knowledge has influenced my working translation. Recipe elements not present that would not be unexpected include: placing spices in a bag to keep them contained, straining spices out, adding some ferment (yeast).
---The context implies the thrice-appearing word has a meaning of add, or put in.
---Braggot is typically identified as a Welsh drink, and recipes are usually in English. The earliest known such recipes are from the late 14th c. To me this suggests the Latin was translated from English in the 15th or 16th c.

My current translation is:

> Recipe to make six lagena (gallons) of servica (ale/beer). Take one lagena of servicie and one quart of honey ??? together over a gentle fire and scum it then/and boil it. Take one ounce of pepper and a little galangal and crush them, and place them in the aforesaid wood (barrel?). Then when it has cooled put it in a clean vessel and then add the specified lagena of servisa to that left behind and stop it up well and let it stand for two ?days? in the vessel ?then? it is drunk.”

I intentionally do not translate names and units of measure, as those are integral to identification and recreation of recipes.

While my primary focus is getting a better transcription, I’m more than happy to hear other thoughts based on Latin language expertise.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site, hard text! I probably won't have a solution, but I have some thoughts that I'll post later. I'll keep the tab open.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.